# user login screen is gone after using panels

Tags: panels, users

I've been trying to login with /user, /?q=user, and /?q=user/login but when I load the pages I can only see my header and nothing else.

This is likely because in the process of trying to learn how to use panels I somehow turned it off.  The default node variant was the first I created, where I put basic header information (site name, slogan, navigation) in the header, body content in the middle, and regular footer content in the footer with the new node-template variant.  As I recall I disabled this page/variant after I realized it applied it to every page and messed up a different system page.  Even though I disabled it and it was fine last time i was on the site, it seems to be back.

Is there any easy way to fix this?  Is there any thing I cut paste into a php file to load my user login block so i can at least get back into my site?

Comment: Have you tried disabling your panels module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used drush to disable panels ( drush dis panels).

Thanks to 4life for the suggestion.  (i don't know why it won't let me credit him with the answer on here)